# Getting the camera to work on an app

Tags: java, android, camera, libgdx

So, I've been referencing this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

I'm using LibGDX which is why you may see some difference, I've also changed mCamera to androidCamera for readability.

Here's my code:

```
package com.fmeg.tapdat.android.camera;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

import com.fmeg.tapdat.android.AndroidLauncher;
import com.fmeg.tapdat.camera.CameraInterface;

public class AndroidCamera extends SurfaceView implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback, CameraInterface {

    private AndroidLauncher application;

    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;

    private Camera androidCamera;

    public AndroidCamera(AndroidLauncher _application) {
        super(_application.getContext());
        this.application = _application;
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        surfaceCreated(mHolder);
    }

    @Override
    public void showCamera(boolean show) {
        androidCamera.startPreview();
    }

    /**
     * Organized by call order
     */
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        androidCamera = Camera.open();
        try {
            androidCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        Camera.Parameters params = androidCamera.getParameters();
        params.setPreviewSize(width, height);
        androidCamera.setParameters(params);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        androidCamera.stopPreview();
        androidCamera = null;
    }


}
```

I have an interface called CameraInterface with the following code:

```
package com.fmeg.tapdat.camera;

public interface CameraInterface {
    public void showCamera(boolean show);
}
```

In my main class (android project) my code looks like this

[code]

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        AndroidCamera cam = new AndroidCamera(this);
        initialize(new TapdatGame(cam), config);
    }

}
```

and in my main class (Core project)

```
package com.fmeg.tapdat;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.fmeg.tapdat.camera.CameraInterface;

public class TapdatGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

    private CameraInterface camera;

    public TapdatGame(CameraInterface cameraInterface) {
        this.camera = cameraInterface;
    }

    @Override
    public void create () {
        camera.showCamera(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    public CameraInterface getCamera() { 
        return camera;
    }

}
```

Please help me get this working, the current implementation invokes an camera realted error

```
Tag(Camera) - Error 1001
```